# Modify data from generator before sending to discriminator

Tags: machine-learning, gan

I am trying to build a GAN, which will take in datasets of size (1, 1800) and generate me similar looking 1-D arrays.

But, I want the generator to output an array of size (1, 400), which will be sent to a function, and that will output an array (1, 1800).

This will be fed to the discriminator as the generated output.

I am finding that user-defined functions can be entered as "Lambda function" Layers between two Dense Layers while compiling the GAN, but I am encountering a 'NoneType' error.

I just wanted to ask if this is possible, or are there any examples like this available?

I can share the code if required.